# Can I use either SQL, MySQL or SQLite to read a SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm not very versed on databases, so thismight sound wrong to some of you: Can I use SQL, MySQL and/or SQLite to read the same database? If so, are there commands or instructions I should keep an eye on to not make a mess on the tables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"make a mess on the tables"?* What do you mean by that statement? This is programming, not cooking.

Comment: You use the same softwware to read the data that you use to write it.  You cannot randomly mix databases.  Their file representations are often not compatible between different versions of the same database, much less between different databases.

Comment: No.  Some commands to avoid are `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` until you know what you're doing.  Just stick with `SELECT` and you should be fine.

Comment: The answer to "*Can I use SQL to read the same database*" is a clear: yes. Both MySQL and SQLite use SQL as a query language.

Answer (score 0):

[sql](/questions/tagged/sql) is a language. [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) and [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) are database engines.

Both SQLite and MySQL (as far as any SQL engines) allows SQL language to manipulate database content (with some engine specific ).

So you may use SQL to read a MySQL or SQLite database. But be aware that SQL use in each is engine dependent. For instance, in SQLite you may use shell application, [c](/questions/tagged/c) wrapper, ... For MySQL you may use [php](/questions/tagged/php) wrapper, ...